# postgresql, restore error, COPY failed for table "pat": ERROR: pattern_in is not implemented

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump, pg-restore

Dump Commond:

```
    pg_dump -Fc test >  /home/backup/test4.sql.gz
```

Restore Commond:

```
    bash-4.1$ pg_restore -d test /home/backup/test4.sql.gz 
    pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error while PROCESSING TOC:

    pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 2408; 0 666136 TABLE DATA pat postgres
    pg_restore: [archiver (db)] COPY failed for table "pat": ERROR:  pattern_in is not implemented
    CONTEXT:  COPY pat, line 1, column ptn: "((0.244171, 0.008272, 0.021515, -0.012174, 0.068765, 0.076409, 0.016820, 0.021921, 0.114738, 0.12366..."
    pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 2445; 0 4877471 TABLE DATA pat_303816 postgres
    pg_restore: [archiver (db)] COPY failed for table "pat_303816": ERROR:  pattern_in is not implemented
    CONTEXT:  COPY pat_303816, line 1, column ptn: "((0.446228, -0.151998, -0.054444, -0.095391, 0.027121, 0.028324, 0.017388, 0.133117, 0.008461, 0.012..."
    pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 2441; 0 4800536 TABLE DATA pat_402653 postgres
    pg_restore: [archiver (db)] COPY failed for table "pat_402653": ERROR:  pattern_in is not implemented
    CONTEXT:  COPY pat_402653, line 1, column ptn: "((0.505515, 0.040819, 0.057495, 0.044649, 0.065036, 0.021012, 0.006341, 0.045162, 0.061616, 0.085675..."
    pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 2449; 0 4878143 TABLE DATA pat_452238 postgres
    pg_restore: [archiver (db)] COPY failed for table "pat_452238": ERROR:  pattern_in is not implemented
    CONTEXT:  COPY pat_452238, line 1, column ptn: "((0.124739, -0.015536, 0.045421, 0.013990, 0.000782, 0.013343, 0.018824, 0.002218, 0.009941, 0.01699..."
    WARNING: errors ignored on restore: 4
```

Comment: Please post text, not images.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, one of your views is referencing a function called `pattern_in`.

You're missing an extension in your database. You'll need to run `CREATE EXTENSION foo` **after** creating the database, but **before** restoring your database from backup. Where `foo` is the name of the extension that provides the `pattern_in` function; I think it could be [this one](https://github.com/postgrespro/imgsmlr).

Comment: I have run this commond before restoring,
`create extension imgsmlr;` 
But there is the same issue.
`pattern_in is not implemented`